# Press ctrl key programatically in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, ctrl

Can someone please tell me how can I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key through javascript code? I want to press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key programaticaly, so that I can select multiple things from mouse clicks. So what i am trying to do is, on click of a button, press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key programatically.

Comment: This sounds like an XY Problem.  What "things" are you trying to "select"?

Comment: Whatever things, for an example, folders. I want to press the ctrl key programaticaly, so that I need not press ctrl key while selecting multiple folders.

Comment: Is this code running inside a browser?  Something else?  What code are you currently using to select a single "folder"?  In what way does it fail when selecting another "folder"?  In what interface are these "folders" and how is the JavaScript code accessing them in the first place?  There's a lot here that isn't entirely clear about the actual problem being solved.

Comment: I have <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" multiple>. So when I browse files, if I want to select multiple files/folders through mouse click, I need to click the ctrl key manually from keyboard. I want to reduce this effort of manually pressing the ctrl key.

Comment: Once a dialog box like that pops up, JS should not be able to click on stuff. That's a major security hole. I'd think you'd want to run a tool on your OS that lets you toggle the ctrl key on/off.

Comment: The scenario of folders was just an example,to understand the use case of pressing ctrl key.  I just want to enable ctrl key through my code on browser, isnt' it possible in the similar ways which we use to enable/trigger other keys on keyboard, similar to - 
jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : "a" }).